The limit of a certain matrix
Let $X$ and $Y$ be positive definite matrices of size $n$.
Then, the following equation holds.
$$(X^{-1} + Y^{-1})^{-1} = X(X+Y)^{-1}Y.$$
I wonder if a minimum eigenvalue of X converges to $0$, does $(X^{-1} + Y^{-1})^{-1}$ converge to $X(X+Y)^{-1}Y$?

There are a couple of ways this question could be interpreted. If you mean that we have some sequence of positive definite matrices $X_n$ converging to a matrix $X$ that is not positive-definite (but necessarily positive-semidefinite), then yes, we will have
$$(X_n^{-1} + Y^{-1})^{-1} \to X(X + Y)^{-1}Y$$
as $n \to \infty$. To show this, we simply observe that $X_n(X_n + Y)^{-1}Y \to X(X + Y)^{-1}Y$, by continuity of matrix addition, multiplication, and inversion on its domain. It's important to note here that $X + Y$, being the sum of a positive-definite and positive-semidefinite matrix, is itself positive-deftinite, and thus invertible, otherwise the continuity of matrix inversion could not be invoked here. Given that $(X_n^{-1} + Y^{-1})^{-1}$ is the same sequence as $X_n(X_n + Y)^{-1}Y$, the above statement is true.

We could interpret your question differently: is it true that,
$$(X_n^{-1} + Y^{-1})^{-1} - X_n(X_n + Y)^{-1}Y \to 0$$
as $n \to \infty$, if $\lambda_\min X_n \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$? In this way, I eschew the implied assumption that $X_n$ converges, positing instead that the two expressions, divergent as they may be, will still grow arbitrarily close to each other. However, this interpretation is false. We could take, for example,
$$X_n = \pmatrix{n & 0 \\ 0 & \frac{1}{n}}, \qquad Y = \pmatrix{2 & -1 \\ -1 & 2}.$$
Then, with a bit of help from Wolfram Alpha, I obtain
$$(X_n^{-1} + Y^{-1})^{-1} - X_n(X_n + Y)^{-1}Y = \pmatrix{\frac{n + \frac{2}{3}}{\frac{2n}{3} + \frac{2}{3n} + \frac{4}{3}} - \frac{2+4n}{2n + \frac{2}{n} + 4} & -\frac{1}{3\left(\frac{2n}{3} + \frac{2}{3n} + \frac{4}{3}\right)} \\
-\frac{1}{3\left(\frac{2n}{3} + \frac{2}{3n} + \frac{4}{3}\right)} & \frac{\frac{1}{n} + \frac{2}{3}}{\frac{2n}{3} + \frac{2}{3n} + \frac{4}{3}} - \frac{2 + \frac{4}{n}}{2n + \frac{2}{n} + 4}}.$$
If we expect this to tend to $0$, the top left entry, for example, should limit to $0$. However,
\begin{align*}
\frac{n + \frac{2}{3}}{\frac{2n}{3} + \frac{2}{3n} + \frac{4}{3}} - \frac{2+4n}{2n + \frac{2}{n} + 4} &= \frac{1 + \frac{2}{3n}}{\frac{2}{3} + \frac{2}{3n^2} + \frac{4}{3n}} - \frac{\frac{2}{n}+4}{2 + \frac{2}{n^2} + \frac{4}{n}} \\
&\to \frac{1 + 0}{\frac{2}{3} + 0 + 0} - \frac{0 + 4}{2 + 0 + 0} = -\frac{1}{2} \neq 0.
\end{align*}
So, no, this alternate formulation doesn't work. Convergence of $X_n$ to some $X$ is necessary; simply considering $\lambda_\min X_n \to 0$ does not suffice.

Thank you! your answer is very good!

My pleasure. Welcome to MSE!
